# Openshift domain list

Tags: dns, openshift

Is there a list of all the domains which have been taken on openshift?  I have spent 20 minutes trying to create a new domain and kept getting message the domain name is already used.  It'd be really helpful if openshift maintains a list so we can look at them before creating one.

Comment: Seems to be off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not currently a list of taken domains.